# How to block the width extension of sibling elements when creating a hover with a css transition

Tags: html, css

I need to increase the width of a list of elements when I hover over a certain element using a CSS transition.
The CSS functionality works, but the problem is that the hover moves the sibling elements. How can this problem be overcome with CSS?

```css
.aside-menu__element {
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.aside-menu__element:hover {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside-menu">
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-long"></i></div>
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i></div>
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i></div>
</div>
```

The link below shows the HTML and CSS code I used: [codepen](https://codepen.io/dgaraux22/pen/MWVKLaX)

Comment: he wants them siblings elements to align to the right so that they wont move (in this case they are moving because they are all aligned to the left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this code

```
.aside-menu { 
  position:fixed;
  right:50px;
  top:150px;
  display: flex;    
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

working sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/shahilparichay/pen/gOePqvW)

```css
.aside-menu {
    position:fixed;
    right:50px;
    top:0px;
   display: flex;    
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.aside-menu__element {
     width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    background-color: #999;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.aside-menu__element:hover {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside-menu">
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-long"></i></div>
    <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i></div>
    <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, it should work.
Add `margin-left: auto;` to `.aside-menu__element` like this.

```css
.aside-menu__element {
    .....;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please, can you make a little bit clear about the issue?

Comment: this works and is more short than mine

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox on the parent element

```css
.aside-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.aside-menu__element {
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.aside-menu__element:hover {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside-menu">
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-long"></i></div>
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i></div>
  <div class="aside-menu__element"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72895462/17235431) was posted 10 mins ago